# Terminal errors - "zsh: command not found" when trying any command

Tags: command-line, terminal, zsh, iterm2, zshrc

I was adding a path to my zshrc file earlier on and after saving the file and re-opening up my Terminal, I've found that I am unable to use any command what so ever.

The error I get back on any command I type in is this:

[image]

No matter what I try typing in I get this error, I have not been able to reopen my zsh file either to remove the paths I added as there is obviously an issue with them.

Can anyone advise the best thing to do to fix this without having to reboot my entire OS?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the macOS Finder to rename the `.zshrc` file to `.Xzshrc`  or something.

- `.zshrc` is in your home directory. One way to navigate to that directory is to enter <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
- Since the filename starts with `.`, it's a hidden file. To get Finder to display hidden files, enter <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

Now you can restart Terminal, and rebuild your `.zshrc` file, copying pieces from `.Xzshrc` as needed. The error is probably in a path assignment.

Comment: Awesome, that worked great, thank you very much! Saved me a headache, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In NVM repository shows how to add source lines to correct profile file:

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Source: [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating)

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Updated my .zsrhc file to this, reopened terminal, and the errors were gone.