# env: bash: No such file or directory macOS terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

i am trying to create a website using python and django on macOS (using a yt tutorial). something must have gone wrong bc every time i'm openeing the terminal now, it says "env: bash: No such file or directory." i've looked at other questions concerning this topic but i honestly don't know what to do bc i can't even use brew anymore.

any help is much appreciated.

i honestly have no idea what to do

Comment: It's probably an incorrect `PATH=` or `path=` setting in your `~/.zshrc` file.  It might be easier to just rebuild that file from scratch; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69768619/9307265) can help get that started.

Comment: You have to debug your zsh startup files. Use the `-x` option on zsh to find out where the error happens (i.e. add a `-x` to the command which currently starts your zsh). Also, read the chapter STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES in the _zsh_ man-page which tells you everything you need to know for the files involved when running a zsh.